# How to configure recipe zope2instance to log to supervisor

Tags: python, logging, supervisord, zope, buildout

What is the designated way to configure `plone.recipe.zope2instance` to log to STDOUT to catch it via supervisor

Setting it to STDOUT like this:

```
[instance]
recipe = plone.recipe.zope2instance
event-log = STDOUT
```

seems to not send anything to supervisor.

If setting

```
event-log = disable
```

no logger backend is found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your buildout.cfg, use the following in your recipe.zope2.instance section:

```
event-log-custom =
  <logfile>
      path STDOUT
      level INFO
  </logfile>
```